# How to place inline two graphs

Tags: tikz-pgf, axis

I have two graphs side by side, but when I add \caption{some my caption text here} the second graph goes to the next line. How to fix that?

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{float}
\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
\begin{figure}[H]
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  xlabel=$t$,
  ylabel=$x(t)$,
  grid=major,
  %step=1cm,
  xmin=-5, xmax=5,
  ymin=-2, ymax=2,
  height=70mm, width=80mm,
  samples=99
  ]
 \addplot[red, thick, line width=1pt]{sin(90*x)+0.5};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Sinusne funcions}
\label{fig:fig1}
\end{figure}
\end{minipage}\hspace*{2pc}%Increase the space how much you like
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
\begin{figure}[H]
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  xlabel=$t$,
  ylabel=$x(t)$,
  grid=major,
  %step=1cm,
  xmin=-5, xmax=5,
  ymin=-2, ymax=2,
  height=70mm, width=80mm,
  samples=99
  ]
 \addplot[red, thick, line width=1pt]{sin(90*x)+0.5};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Sinusne functions}
\label{fig:fig2}
\end{figure}  
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please provide the `MWE`

Comment: Here it is in comment below

Comment: Floats are supposed to be in outer par mode, not inside a minipage.  Admittedly [H] (possibly the worst idea ever) doesn't really float.

Comment: oh thank you for saying me that's the worst idea ever, and nothing about solution :D

Comment: Not using it, creating it.

Answer (score 1):

Try with the below:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{float}
\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
\begin{figure}[H]
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  xlabel=$t$,
  ylabel=$x(t)$,
  grid=major,
  %step=1cm,
  xmin=-5, xmax=5,
  ymin=-2, ymax=2,
  height=70mm, width=80mm,
  samples=99
  ]
 \addplot[red, thick, line width=1pt]{sin(90*x)+0.5};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Sinusne funcions}
\label{fig:fig1}
\end{figure}
\end{minipage}\hspace*{2pc}%Increase the space how much you like
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
\begin{figure}[H]
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  xlabel=$t$,
  ylabel=$x(t)$,
  grid=major,
  %step=1cm,
  xmin=-5, xmax=5,
  ymin=-2, ymax=2,
  height=70mm, width=80mm,
  samples=99
  ]
 \addplot[red, thick, line width=1pt]{sin(90*x)+0.5};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Sinusne functions}
\label{fig:fig2}
\end{figure}  
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just reverse the order of figure and minipage.  Then all you have to do is shrink the tikzpictures until they actually fit into the minipages.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{showframe}% MWE only
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[H]
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  xlabel=$t$,
  ylabel=$x(t)$,
  grid=major,
  %step=1cm,
  xmin=-5, xmax=5,
  ymin=-2, ymax=2,
  height=70mm, width=80mm,
  samples=99
  ]
 \addplot[red, thick, line width=1pt]{sin(90*x)+0.5};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Sinusne funcions}
\label{fig:fig1}
\end{minipage}\hfil
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  xlabel=$t$,
  ylabel=$x(t)$,
  grid=major,
  %step=1cm,
  xmin=-5, xmax=5,
  ymin=-2, ymax=2,
  height=70mm, width=80mm,
  samples=99
  ]
 \addplot[red, thick, line width=1pt]{sin(90*x)+0.5};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Sinusne functions}
\label{fig:fig2}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```